# MailKit shows message body as null

Tags: powershell, mailkit

So I have hMailServer running locally and send emails using powershell script as shown below:

```
$SMTPMessage.Subject = "Margin Call Notice 1"
$SMTPMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true
$SMTPMessage.Body = "Some body message"
    
$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$SMTPClient.EnableSSL = $false
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

When I read this email via mailKit, for some reason Body (HtmlBody, TextBody, Body properties) is always null, no mater if I set IsBodyHtml to true or to false.

I read messages like that:

```
    private IEnumerable<IMessageSummary> GetUnreadMessages(ImapClient client)
    {
        client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
        var uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);
        var messages = client.Inbox.Fetch(uids, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope);
        return messages;
    }
```

And then message.Body, message.TextBody and message.HtmlBody is null and message.BodyParts is empty.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Post your MailKit code that has a null Body.

Comment: updated original question

Answer (score 1):

Your Fetch request specifically asks for only the UID and The ENVELOPE info which means that the IMessageSummary.Body will always be null.

If you want the Body property to be non-null, you should include `MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure` in your Fetch request.

Comment: Ok, I added Body and BodyStructure to fetch request, so now it looks like: client.Inbox.Fetch(uids, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.BodyStructure | MessageSummaryItems.Body) Where in the message object then should I see email body? I see  message.Body,ContentDescription property is equal to message subject, but there is nothing that looks like my message body.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out :-)

Answer (score 1):

Found how to get message body:

```
var bodyPart = message.TextBody;

// download the 'text/plain' body part
var body = (TextPart)client.Inbox.GetBodyPart(message.UniqueId, bodyPart);
var text = body.Text;
```